# How to know if any application running?

Tags: android, service

I am writing an service using that I want to detect if any application is running or not.

Is there any API support available for same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 

List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString()
    .equalsIgnoreCase(getApplicationContext().getPackageName().toString())) {                                               
        isActivityFound = true;
    }
    else{                                                            
       isActivityFound = false;
    }
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

And for all activities see this link

http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/